# Prove that there exists a monic polynomial of degree $l$ for any points $(\alpha_1,\beta_1), (\alpha_2,\beta_2),...,(\alpha_l, \beta_l)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Prove that there exists a unique monic polynomial of degree $l$ for any points $(\alpha_1,\beta_1), (\alpha_2,\beta_2),...,(\alpha_l, \beta_l),$ $ l\ge 1$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{K}\times\mathbb{K}$ that interpolates them.
>
> I already know how to prove uniqueness
>
> monic: The number in front of the first term is 1:  $1\cdot x^3+x^2+x+1$

For example, take the points (-1,0), (0,0), (1,4), those get interpolated by $g(x) = 2x^2+2x$ (**degree 2**). Playing with the values in a plotter shows there exists a polynomial $p(x) = x^3+2x^2+x-0$ of **degree 3** that interpolates those points too:

[image]

**My ideas:**

(1) At any rate, we have to find a rule to constructs the monic term.

(2) The Newton-Interpolationformula-algorithm gives us the polynomial of degree l-1, we can probably reuse this to construct the higher-degree-polynomial.

Comment: @Jack I stumbled upon it, but it does interpolate with the lowest degree, what I want is the next higher degree and there the monic polynomial. For reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial is bascially the same as larange if im not mistaken

Comment: I think you meant degree $l-1$. You can always add an arbitrary point to get a unique degree $l$ polynomial. So degree $l$ polynomial is not unique. It is easy to achieve a monic polynomial. Just divide by the first coefficient.

Comment: @KittyL Degree l polynomial is unique, wouldn't dividing by the first coefficient mean, that the polynomial doesn't interpolate the given points anymore?

Comment: You are right. Sorry I didn't think. So the monic condition is to ensure the uniqueness. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. Suppose the polynomial is
$$a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{l-1}x^{l-1}+x^l=y.$$

Putting the last term to the right hand side, we get
$$a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{l-1}x^{l-1}=y-x^l.$$

Now use Newton's interpolation on the points:

$$\{(\alpha_i, \beta_i-\alpha_i^l)| i=1,\dots, l\}.$$

This means, treating $\beta_i-\alpha_i^l$ as the $y$ values. So the problem transforms to the original problem of finding a unique polynomial of degree $l-1$ with $l$ points.

Comment: This is genius, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the desired monic polynomial
$$
p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+x^k
$$
for $(x_i,y_i)$ with $i=1,\cdots, k$. One should assume that all these points are distinct. Then the condition $p(x_i)=y_i$ gives you a linear equation on the $a_i$'s. The solution of the linear equation gives you the existence of $p(x)$.

Now what you need is knowing the property of [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).